# Directional derivative (Vector)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, self-learning

> Given $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a map $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ is a point, then how does one show that $f$ is differentiable (or not) in the direction $v=(v_1,v_2)$?

For example, what if $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$ and $\alpha=(0, \pi/3)$ and $v=(9,12)$?  **Given that this function apparently has a directional derivative at $\alpha$, how does one go about to show this using the definition?**

---

Is it to show that that the Jacobian is defined at $\alpha$ and then multiply this by the direction vector $v$ (which has been normalized)?

The definition of differentiation is as follows
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{|f(\overline{x}+\overline{h})-f(\overline{x})-A\overline{h}|}{|\overline{h}|}=0
\end{equation}

I have calculated
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix} e^x \cos y &-e^x\sin y \\ e^x \sin y & e^x \cos y \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and so at $\alpha =(0, \pi/3)$
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2 \\ \sqrt{3}/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Therefore, if \begin{align} f(\overline{\alpha}+\overline{h})&=(e^{0+h}\cos (\pi/3+h), e^{0+h}\sin(\pi /3 +h)) \\ &=(e^h [\cos (\pi/3)\cos(h)-\sin(\pi/3)\sin(h)], e^h[\cos(\pi/3)\sin (h)+\cos (h)\sin(\pi/3]) \\ & =\end{align}

Comment: There are a number of ways. You can show that the function is not differentiable at the point, you can show the directional derivative is not linear in $v$. Without a specific case it's hard to tell what's best.

Comment: That function is differentiable because all components functions are differentiable. What do you know about characterizations of differentiable functions?

Comment: I know that if a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then all the partial derivatives must exist at $\alpha$ and the derivative is given as the Jacobian matrix. I don't have any trouble showing this using the actual definition of differentiation but I do when it comes to directional derivative of the higher order types like $f(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$. I am confused as to how I should deal with $\nabla f$.

Comment: The gradient is only defined for functions $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$. In your case the directional derivative will be a vector. The derivative of a $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ is a linear mapping of $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$. When you apply the vector for the directional derivative you'll get another vector. But what I've said before also works in this case. You can show that $Df(\alpha)$ does not exist, or that $Df(\alpha)(v)$ is not linear in $v$.

Comment: Should I apply the directional vector on the Jacobian?

Comment: Yes. That is what $Df(\alpha)(v)$ means. :)